# CakePHP Email Component

Tags: email, cakephp

Any reason why when I include the Email component in my controller without writing any code for it:

```
var $components = array('Email');
```

I get a fatal error saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object
```

I assume this is relating to the $Session variable, when I comment the component out, the error disappears.

Comment: 1. Which controller?
2. In which file and line does this error appear?
3. What is in this line?

Comment: The component is loaded into the AppController and the error is on line 116 of the AppController inside another method: $layout = $this->Session->read('shop.layout.style');

Comment: Definitely a conflict with the Session->read(), just put together a fresh app added the component to the AppController set up another controller and on the index() method called $this->Session->read('test'); and I get the same error/problem.

Comment: It appears the Session component is loaded by default yet if I define var $components = array('Email') in my AppController and don't include Session in the array it is then removed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Session component is loaded by default yet if I define var $components = array('Email') in my AppController and don't include Session in the array it is then removed.

Answer (score 0):

After your comments I suggest you write `var $components = array('Email', 'Session')`, this should get you rid of your error.
The problem is, that the AppController components don't get merged with the defaults. That means, if you declare the components with just 'Email', your Session-component will be lost and you therefore get this error because $this->Session is not an object.